# Geometric meaning of trace?

Tags: linear-algebra

The determinant of a matrix has a geometric meaning in terms of volume. Does the trace have some geometric meaning as well?

Comment: See also [How to geometrically interpret $\sum^{p}_{1}\lambda_{i}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/263540/264)